# DVWA SQL Injection Not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have set up DVWA on my localhost in order to see the different functions available to it but I am running into some trouble. I have set everything up ok and I am able to login in fine.

The problem occurs when I try use the SQL injection function. I am able to get a result by typing in the user ID but if I try any injections that arnt numbers the screen just resets itself and nothing happens.

In the installation instructions it mentions that if SQL injection isnt working to change some lines in the . htaccess file.

I cannot seem to find this file any where at all. I have looked in the htdocs directory and the DVWA directory but cannot seem to find it.

Can anyone help point me to the right location? I am using a mac and XAMPP 5.6 if that makes any different.

Answer (score 0):

There is a config.php file you need to edit and somewhere towards the bottom is a line of code that sets the default security level. Change it from `impossible` to `low`.

The config.php folder is in the `htdocs>DVWA>config`.